# manually set access token in iOS SDK 3.1.1 for FBSession

Tags: objective-c, facebook, session

I have an access token and I'd like FBSession to open an active session with that particular access token. How can I do so with the new Facebook SDK? It seems that the access token is read only.

The issue here is that when I am offline or don't have an internet connection. But someone has connected his/her facebook account. Then I need to somehow know this. But yet there is no way to do that currently with the current SDK

Comment: I don't want to extend it, I just want to know whether the user has connected their facebook account or not